# Thread detection and assignment to CPU, who does the work? compiler? OS? CPU?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing, cpu, compiler-optimization

I want to know when you have multi-core processor, does any one detect the independent chunk of code and create a new thread and assign it to an idle CPU?

I know that newer CPUs tries to do that. but I don't know enough about compiler and OS.

so can someone please explain to me, how much work will be done by compiler, OS and CPU?

Thanks

Update:
Sorry if my question was so vague, lets assume we have a code that translate to below instruction set.

```
add $1,$2,$3
nand $3,$2,$4
lw $2,$5,imm
```

10000 more instruction
......

```
add $65,$66,$67
add $67,$65,$68
```

10000 more instruction

and I assume instructions between lower and upper set are independent of each other.
now the below instructions can be send to another core for execution instead of waiting on the upper set to finish.

my question is who try to identify this independent blocks and send them to different cores.

thanks again.

Comment: Usually kernel does that.

Comment: does compiler and CPU try to do so ?

Comment: @shekharsuman in high level computer architecture class, my professor mentioned that CPU will do that, he didn't explained more and I didn't find anything about it. does compiler try to create concurrent threads?

Comment: What are "concurrent threads in one program thread" anyway? Are you referring to superscalar execution?

Comment: @Harold superscalar execution is very interesting and I'm going to read more about it, but what I meant was block of instruction that are independent of rest of the code, and can be assigned to another core as a thread.

Comment: A given block of code could execute on any number of threads in any number of processes. The mapping of code to thread comes from the application, the mapping of thread to CPU is performed by the OS. Think of some block of code that computes square root - it could be used by any number of programs, in any number of processes, in any number of threads. You really need to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @Mars no one detects those. Well, the programmer, maybe.

Comment: @Harold if no one detects those, is there any way to program somehow that this blocks be assigned to different cores?

Comment: ^^ what @antiduh says above.  You seem to be confused as to what a thread is and how it is managed.   A compiler cannot do anything because it is not around when code is has generated is run.  Maybe read an OS book?

Comment: @Mars yes, explicitly. The programmer can call an os function that creates a thread. There are some libraries that manage it a bit more implicitly, but in the end of the day it's the programmer who says which things can be run in different threads.

Answer (score 1):

In ye olde days, threads were managed by libraries and in some case with the compiler as well. Ada compilers of the 80's vintage were a good example of that.

Now, in the days of multi-processors and operating systems that support them, threads tend to be managed by the operating system. The operating system picks the processor to use.

There are few programming languages that have real threading support (e.g., Ada) so compilers tend to have little involvement in multithreading.